# How to fix Django error: DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: ... You may need to add ... to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, http-host

I am trying to develop a website using Django framework and launched using DigitalOcean.com and deployed the necessary files into django-project.

I had to include static files into Django-project and After collecting static files, I tried to refresh my ip

I am including the tutorials which I have used to create the website.
https://www.pythonprogramming.net/django-web-server-publish-tutorial/

I am getting the following error :

> DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '198.211.99.20'. You may
>   need to add u'198.211.99.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Can somebody help me to fix this ? This is my first website using Django framework.

Comment: That may also be your Floating IP address on DigitalOcean.

Comment: Can I use my external IP for starting the server?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The error log is straightforward. As it suggested,You need to add **198.211.99.20**  to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

In your project settings.py file,set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` like this :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['198.211.99.20', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

For further reading
[read from here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

Comment: Now getting the following error 
Request URL: 198.211.99.20 Exception Type:TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value: personal/home.html Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/temp‌​late/loader.py in get_template, line 25
I have my templates in the following folder /home/django/django_project/personal/templates/personal

Comment: @Kathir There are many examples of that error.Just google it and if the problem still continues,then please ask it as a separate question,comments are not very descriptive.

Comment: This definitely works but is bad practice as you should always use a .env file

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj could you please explain a little more or share a link with more explanation?

Comment: @JesusAlmaral Here you go https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings :)

Comment: @JesusAlmaral A .env file is a local file containing passwords and other sensitive information. If you put all this sensitive information inside your code itself then it could get compromised. Thus we use this local file .env and everyone stores with their own passwords etc locally

Comment: The problem is that I suspect these events induced by various bots I think. I don't want to pollute my settings.py with all kind of bot's IPs, especially they can vary. I rather want to suppress this message all together

Comment: @CsabaToth If you go to the provided link, you can see that you can suppress the warning by adding ALLOWED_HOSTS = []  so, please read the whole answer before downvoting.

Comment: I don't want to empty the ALLOWED_HOSTS either, but I'll remove the downvote

Comment: I run my project using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and have multiple server instances. I get these errors as well. I can't just add the IPs to fix the problem because they change constantly. I would be updating it everyday.

Comment: I used dotenv to store the values locally, and then also include them as environment variables on production: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
Like this:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    'app.mysite.com',
    os.environ.get('SERVER_IP')
]

Comment: FWIW, in our case, all accesses by the naked IP address are dubious. Our solution was to configure the web server to reject all `Host` headers not matching the ones Django accepts.

Comment: If I add the ip address 198.211.99.20 to ALLOWED_HOSTS after the error message: “Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '198.211.99.20' that would solve the DISALLOWED HOST problem. But wouldn't that cause problems in the future since I'm using auto scaling? Since that could lead to new instances being created with new IP addresses if there is enough trafic. So i'm gonna have to hard code the new IP addresses into ALLOWED_HOSTS every time that happens?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # if you are in dev or docker
```

Don't do this in production if you are not using docker, just put the IP address.

Comment: As pydanny said "...don't leave it as such once you get this figured out. The reason is that makes Django potentially vulnerable to HTTP_HOST header attacks. And automated scripts scour the internet to check if sites have this vulnerability."
https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/914#issuecomment-263614761

Comment: Lol, that is for development env. in production only need set DEBUG=False.

Comment: You do not want to use '*' for production. This completely bypasses the reason and security of the allowed hosts.

Comment: @AndyPoquette generally you're right, but using docker (and not exposing the backend's port, but using a reverse proxy like nginx) it's OK to use '*' even for production.

Comment: Never, NEVER do this! Allowed * is a primary security error. Only do this in development mode!

Comment: @artem is this correct? I'm using Django with docker in production and I'm receiving some emails with that error. Do you think it's a good idea anyway? You have an article talking about that?

Comment: Depending on how you expose your docker container this can still be a security issue. Its best to actually connfigure the correct IP addresses / domain names instead.

Answer (score 2):

In your project settings.py file,set ALLOWED_HOSTS like this :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['62.63.141.41', 'namjoosadr.com']
```

and then restart your apache. in ubuntu:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to your settings file or `env` file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".localhost", "127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if no other answer work you can try modifying manage.py and add this three lines

```
from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
import django.http.request
django.http.request.host_validation_re = _lazy_re_compile(r"[a-zA-z0-9.:]*")
```

to end up having something like this:

```
import os
import sys

from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
import django.http.request    
django.http.request.host_validation_re = _lazy_re_compile(r"[a-zA-z0-9.:]*")

def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project01.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

as it is explained in this post: [How to Solve "The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035" in Django during Development](https://notabela.hashnode.dev/how-to-solve-the-domain-name-provided-is-not-valid-according-to-rfc-10341035-in-django-during-development)

Answer (score 0):

I was testing my Django app on `minikube` and because of the probes, it was failing with the following error:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '10.244.0.8:8080'. You may need to add '10.244.0.8' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /
```

I added the `httpHeaders` in my probes and it worked after that.

Before:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: / # Replace with an endpoint that returns a 200 status code if the app is healthy
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 10 # Delay before the first probe is executed
  periodSeconds: 10 # How often to perform the probe
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: / # Replace with an endpoint that indicates readiness
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 5 # Delay before the first probe is executed
  periodSeconds: 5 # How often to perform the probe
```

After:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: / # Replace with an endpoint that returns a 200 status code if the app is healthy
    port: 8080
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Host
      value: localhost
  initialDelaySeconds: 10 # Delay before the first probe is executed
  periodSeconds: 10 # How often to perform the probe
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: / # Replace with an endpoint that indicates readiness
    port: 8080
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Host
      value: localhost
  initialDelaySeconds: 5 # Delay before the first probe is executed
  periodSeconds: 5 # How often to perform the probe
```