# Issues with accessing Django app on remote server; manually assigning IP address does not work

Tags: django, python-3.x, localhost, remote-server

I've set up a CentOS7 dev environment on a remote server in order for my team to view the site as I continue to build it. Unfortunately every time I try to run python manage.py runserver, I receive the default Django IP address (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) for the server. When I try to access the app using it, the page is routed to a Yahoo Search Engine page (which means there are usually issues finding the IP). When I try to manually set the IP address(0.0.0.0:8000), I am still rerouted to the YSE page.

```
python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 07, 2017 - 15:56:45
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 07, 2017 - 16:19:43
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

The instance was created using a existing Bitbucket repo that uses my local computer instance as the the source.

When the server is running, it does not inform me of any errors or issues with spinning up the app. What exactly could be the problem? Has anyone else dealt with an issue like this?
Any help that you can provide is appreciated.

**EDIT**: The linked thread does not fully answer the question. This thread ([Access Django app from other computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550116/access-django-app-from-other-computers)) solves the problem. You must uses the 0.0.0.0:8000 when assigning the IP address through the runserver command.  Then in the web browser, use the remote server's ip address in place of the zeros: remote.server.ip.addressgoeshere:8000.

Comment: What is "the stock django IP address for the server"?

Comment: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/)

Comment: Well,, that is the localhost address. If you want to make your site available externally you need to bind it to your computer's actual IP address.